Config field is lost after callonce sleep
baseUrl is a parameter coming from the karate-config-unit.js.
...
return {
   baseUrl:'http://localhost:' + port,
}

Sleep method:
Background:     
def sleep = function(pause){ java.lang.Thread.sleep(pause * 1000) }

And inside scenario it works fine until callonce sleep call.

Why is it lost?  Current version 1.5.0.RC3. Before updating (in version 1.1.0.RC3) it was not behaving like this

submit a way to replicate please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

@PeterThomas Ok. Will do so. Made an edit here to show what sleep method is. Maybe this will give some additional idea.

@PeterThomas issue opened: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2548
